# DrawString on an image with relatively small font

Tags: c#, fonts, bitmap

I want to create a bmp file (in C#) with text written on it. This bmp is really small (120*70) and the required font size is 5. Once I create this bmp the text is not readable. Is there a way to solve this?

I have already used

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

But no luck

Comment: Font size 5 is not readable, what did you expect? Very few fonts will have identifiable characters in font size 5. Just to clarify, you mean 5pt? An image of your current results would be good to add.

Comment: You could create a font that works in 5pt -> it's possible, I've seen it done and done it myself. But as Yorye said, no normal font will support that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to success is mainly the chosen Font. This seems to go to the limit:

[image]

It uses the [smallest-pixel-7 font](http://www.dafont.com/de/smallest-pixel-7.font) and writes to the bitmap like this:

```
string testText = "The quick brown fox <_>°|^ 123456789-0!";

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp0))
using (Font font = new Font("Smallest Pixel-7", 10f))
{
    G.TextContrast = 0;
    G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    G.DrawString(testText, font, Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 20));
}
```

Most characters fit in a 5 pixel height, some use the 6th pixel line, like the 'Q' and I guess the 7th line is for leading..

Note the it is all caps and watch their license! (There ought to be a freeware font as well..like maybe [here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/19/34-free-and-elegant-truetype-mini-pixel-fonts/))

In my tests `AntiAliasGridFit` was the best option, much better than `AntiAlias`:

> Each character is drawn using its antialiased glyph bitmap with
>   hinting. Much better quality due to antialiasing, but at a higher
>   performance cost.

**Note 2:** The bitmap's dpi resolution is directly related to the necessary font size. In the 1st example 72 dpi were used. If you increase the resolution  you can reduce the font size.

```
bmp0.SetResolution(150, 150);
```

The example below used 72dpi and a fontsize of 9.6pt.

Here is a selection of various other fonts; if you can't read the font family you don't want to use it ;-)

(I have added a line every 5 pixels so you can compare the actual heights.)

[image]